# Is there a "one-liner" for submitting many jobs to SLURM (similar to LSF)?

Tags: slurm, lsf, sbatch

Can I submit "one-liners" to SLURM?

Using `bsub` from LSF and the standard Linux utility `xargs`, I can easily submit a separate job for uncompressing all of the files in a directory:

```
ls *.gz | sed 's/.gz$//g' | xargs -I {} bsub 'gunzip -c {}.gz > {}'
```

Using SLURM, I thought that `srun` or `sbatch` would be work, but to no avail:

```
ls *.gz | sed 's/.gz$//g' | xargs -I {}  srun 'gunzip -c {}.gz > {}'
gzip: srun: error: compute-node-01: task 0: Exited with exit code 1
stdin: unexpected end of file

ls *.gz | sed 's/.gz$//g' | xargs -I {}  sbatch 'gunzip -c {}.gz > {}'
sbatch: error: Unable to open file gunzip -c naive_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz > naive_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq
```

I have seen `bsub` from LSF [listed as equivalent](http://umbc.rnet.missouri.edu/resources/Submitting_Jobs_via_SLURM.html#slurmvslsf) to `sbatch` from SLURM, but so far it seems that they are only equivalent for submitting script files:

```
                  SLURM                    LSF
                  --------------------     ------------------
Job Submission    sbatch [script_file]     bsub [script_file]
```

Is there any other way to submit "one-liner" jobs with SLURM?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the wrap option of [`sbatch`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html). Something like the following:

```
ls *.gz | sed 's/.gz$//g' | xargs -I {}  sbatch --wrap="gunzip -c {}.gz > {}"
```

From the man page for `sbatch`:

```
--wrap=<command string>
       Sbatch will wrap the specified command string in  a  simple  "sh"  shell
       script,  and submit that script to the slurm controller.  When --wrap is
       used, a script name and arguments may not be specified  on  the  command
       line; instead the sbatch-generated wrapper script is used.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also pipe into `sbatch`. Here's an example

```
echo '#!/bin/bash
touch hello_slurm.txt
' | sbatch -e err.log -o out.log
```

This could be "forced" into one line and also works well along with `xargs -n1`, but I think it is more readable this way to illustrate the idea.

Personally I prefer `heredoc` here, because it adds some more flexibility if the embedded "one-liner" or "some-liner" contains single quotes as well (which makes it imho also a more general solution compared to `sbatch --wrap`):

```
sbatch  -e err.log -o out.log <<"EOF"
#!/bin/bash
touch 'hello_slurm2.txt'
EOF
```

Btw, since it was mentioned in the question as well: the same approach works for `bsub` when using LSF.

Comment: The problem with a heredoc is that its difficult to use within a Makefile

Comment: Interesting. Perhaps use `echo -e ""` to build up a multiline script and then pipe it into `sbatch`... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Carles Fenoy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29819952/215487), I created a utility called [sbatch_run](https://github.com/molecules/Perl6-misc/blob/master/sbatch_run).

This script takes a job name and your command in quotes and then creates the script for you (and runs it for you).

```
sbatch_run jobname 'ls -lArt > list_of_files.txt'
```

Will create the following script and run it for you:

```
#!/bin/env bash
#SBATCH -J jobname.sbatch
#SBATCH -o jobname.sbatch.o_%j
#SBATCH -e jobname.sbatch.e_%j
#SBATCH --partition c14,general,HighMem
#SBATCH --mem 5G
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 1
#SBATCH --nodes 1
#SBATCH --time 2-0

ls -lArt > list_of_files.txt
```

There are options for setting memory and cpus per task, etc.